# Changing one value affects another

Tags: php

Please have a look at the following:

```
foreach($a_Header['Details'] as $i_Detail => &$a_Detail)
    {
    echo "{$a_Detail['VEH_TREAD_OFF']}\n";

    // Make a back-up of the value
    $BAK_TREAD_OFF = $a_Detail['VEH_TREAD_OFF'];

    // Copy some data from the saved header
    foreach(array
        (
        'POD_QTYORD',
        'VEH_TREAD_OFF',
        'RPM_SCRM_FIXEDPRICE',
        'RPM_TRM_FIXEDPRICE',
        'RPM_TRM_COSTPERMM',
        'RPM_CTS_CASINGCOST',
        'CHARGE_DESC',
        'Hide',
        ) as $s_Column)
        {
        $a_Header['Details'][$i_Detail][$s_Column] = $a_SavedHeader['Details'][$i_Detail][$s_Column];
        }

    echo "{$a_Detail['VEH_TREAD_OFF']}\n";

    // Now restore our value
    $a_Detail['VEH_TREAD_OFF'] = $BAK_TREAD_OFF;
    }
```

You can see that prior to entering the for loop, I have backed up a value which I restore after.

This is because for some reason it is being lost during the loop.

I'm not a PHP guru by any stretch, but this is confusing me no end, as I can't see why modifying one variable would affect another, unless there are wormholes in PHP!

Can someone tell me why this might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: How do you see it's being lost?

Comment: Before I added the "backup and restore" code, I `echo`d the contents out which showed a value before and no value after.

Comment: I can't see anything in the code you show that would destroy `$a_Detail['VEH_TREAD_OFF'];`. Is this 100% the code in question? You are not inside a function with this or something? (In PHP, functions have their own scope)

Comment: Where does `$a_Detail` come from? How do you initialize it?

Comment: Updated code now to show where `$a_Detail` comes from. Notice the `&` - I'm wondering if this creates a reference rather than a new variable - ?

Comment: Well, I just Googled it and it seems that's exactly what it does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i_Detail => &$a_Detail
```

Now `$a_Detail` is a reference to `$a_Header['Details'][$i_Detail]`. both variables refer to a single value. Do not use `&` if you do not want that.

Comment: Thanks, I already figured that thanks to the above comments. It's not my code incidentally.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample does not affect $a_detail at all. Are you sure, this is the only reference to this variable? Do you use something like extract()?

Comment: You see why I was confused then? But actually you're wrong, as I was. The variable $a_detail is defined as a reference to an element of $a_header['detail'], so what changes one will change the other.